# Internet Connected disconnected after submitted the request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am requesting two web services 
 Example : one for ebay and another for amazon.

I submitted the request to both webservice at once.

When i am disconnected the Internet after submitting request.

I am expecting this delegate method need to call but its not at all calling.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try decrease the timeout interval (requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:) for your request. It's 60s by default.

Is your class defined as delegate for the connection ?

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLRequest